# Change StatusBar to White

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I'm trying to change the status bar color to white just on one activity, but the icons barely apear:

[image]

I'm using this code:

```
 Window window = getWindow();
 window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
 window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
 window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

I can't change the ColorPrimaryDark, because I already set one color for all app.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I was commenting on a beginner error. This have a very simple solution, that is just set a theme for this activity on manifest file:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

And this java code on my Activity, as @shahab said:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Have you tried: `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` in your styles? It's because you're making it transparent : `Color.TRANSPARENT` that's why that happens.

Comment: @shmosel, I want the icons to appear when the bar is white

Answer (score 4, accepted):

changing status bar color is available just for android above lollipop

1.you can change status bar color programmatically by this line:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color));
}
```

2.you can do this with an smooth transition animation:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    int startColor = getWindow().getStatusBarColor();
    int endColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
    ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(getWindow(), "statusBarColor", startColor, endColor).start();
}
```

3.or you can add this to your theme style in values/styles.xml file. item colorPrimaryDark will be used for your app status bar color

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

---

but for changing status bar icon color to dark you can use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR flag that is available for android above M

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
}
```

or add it to your theme style xml:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in `onCreate()` method :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

This works from API 23+.

Answer (score 0):

```
Window window = getWindow();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

else {
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```